# How can a Mutual Fund that is not an ETF be traded on an exchange?

Tags: mutual-funds, germany

Have a look at https://www.onvista.de/fonds/DJE-Zins-Dividende-PA-EUR-Fonds-LU0553164731. It is the information page for a regular fund ("mutual fund"), not an ETF. Nevertheless, it has a dropdown box for choosing the exchange it is traded at, as well as the entry "KVG" (Kapitalverwaltungsgesellschaft, company which issues the funds).

How is it possible that this funds is traded at several exchanges?

Comment: You should look at the Key Investor information PDF. I cannot read German. If it is an open ended mutual fund, it would have a net asset value that is determined end of day each day. If it is a closed-ended fund, it could be listed and traded at several exchanges not just one.